# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^{3}(t)}{\sin^{3}(t)+\cos^{3}(t)}dt$ by hands

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the following integral by hands:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^{3}(t)}{\sin^{3}(t)+\cos^{3}(t)}dt$$

It seems apparently that integration by part does not work. I think integration by substitution could work but I can not figure out how to substitute.

I have calculated it by Wolfram and the result is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I think Weierstrass substitution might help.

Comment: If you needed the indefinite intregral, you could divide by $\cos^3t$ and substitute $t=\tan^{-1}x$ or divide by $\cos^5t$ and substitute $x=\tan t$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write:
$$\frac{\sin^3 t}{\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t} = 1-\frac{\cos^3 t}{\sin^3t+\cos^3t}$$

Apply the symmetry $\sin t = \cos(\frac\pi2 - t)$ to conclude that the integrals over the fractions are equal. The result from Wolfram follows.

While conceptually different, the use of symmetry is similar in effect to the substitution proposed by @Norbert.

Comment: I'm pretty sure _symmetry_ is just what Norbert had in mind, even though he didn't use that word.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I have followed your solution but what's next? I found that it is still difficult to find the indefinite integral and then solve the definite integral.

Comment: When I wrote "integrals over the fractions" I meant the definite integrals. The indefinite integrals of these two fractions can't be equal obviously. If this comment doesn't make sense to you, it means I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Make change of varianles $$t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$$

Comment: You can actually show what $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\dfrac{{{{\sin }^n}x}}{{{{\sin }^n}x + {{\cos }^n}x}}dx} $ is for every $n$ with the very same substitution.

Comment: Maybe you could also generalize this $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\dfrac{{f({{\sin }}x)}}{{f({{\sin }}x) + f({{\cos }}x)}}dx}$